# HTML email submit form

Tags: html, forms, email

Having a problem with an email form. When clicking submit doesn't recognize page. Am I missing something really obvious? I've replaced 'your email address' for a valid email address in VALUE.

Here is the code:

```
<form method="post" action="http://www.ftp://www.users.greenbee.net//cgi-bin/FormMail.pl" name="MyForm">

<input type="hidden" name="recipient" value="YOUR EMAIL ADDRESS" />
<input type="hidden" name="sort" value="order:FirstName,Surname,emailaddress,Comments" />

<center>

<table border="0" width="64%" bgcolor="#c0c0c0">
<tr>
  <td width="41%" align="center"><strong>First Name</strong></td>
  <td width="59%" align="center"><input type="text" name="FirstName" size="24" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td width="41%" align="center"><strong>Surname</strong></td>
  <td width="59%" align="center"><input type="text" name="Surname" size="24" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td width="41%" align="center"><strong>E-mail Address</strong></td>
  <td width="59%" align="center"><input type="text" name="emailaddress" size="24" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td width="41%" align="center"><strong>Comments on my webpage</strong></td>
  <td width="59%" align="center"><textarea rows="3" cols="24" name="Comments"></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td width="41%" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Send Form" name="SendForm" /></td>
  <td width="59%" align="center"><input type="reset" value="Clear Form" name="ClearForm" /></td>
</tr>
</table>

</center>

</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The form `action` is all messed up.

It should be either `http://` or `ftp://` you can't combine both.

From quick trial and error, this one "works" though requires authentication:
`ftp://www.users.greenbee.net/cgi-bin/FormMail.pl`

Answer (score 1):

you have invalid Action Page with this
see There is a two Protocols

Http and FTP..

I think it is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

check your action path. it must be absolute location of your FormMail.pl.

be sure starts with http:// or ftp://

Answer (score 0):

There’s a relatively new service called [Slapform](https://slapform.com) that allows you to send yourself form submissions via email.  All you have to do is set the form’s `method` to `POST` and point the form’s `action` to `https://api.slapform.com/your@email.com`.  It’s very simple and easy to use:

```js
<form method="POST"
  action="https://api.slapform.com/your@email.com">
  <input type="email" name="email">
  <textarea type="text" name="message"></textarea>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```